# Visual Studio doesn't re-compile

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I created a simple WinForms application with a Button on it on a certain location (just dragged and dropped it from the toolbox, so it landed somewhere in the middle of the form) and when pressed the F5, it worked okay.

But, then I closed the form and got back to the studio. I just dragged and dropped the Button somewhere else and now when I run it with F5, in the running program the Button remained at the same location like before.

I cleaned the solution, rebuild it manually and run again. The same happened.
I dragged and dropped the button again somewhere else and the situation was the same as for the first time.

After 2 or 3 complies finally it worked...

Have anyone of you met this problem before? What's the solution? Thank you.

Comment: Did you save the form? Is the application shutting down correctly? Are there any warnings or errors in the Output tab in VS?

Comment: 1: Yes, 2: Yes, 3: No.

Comment: Make sure that after debugging you actually hit the stop button, and not just close the winform.

Comment: Happened to me sometimes in VS 2008. Manually deleting the executable then compiling solved at the time.

Comment: Okay, the debugging was stopped.
(Otherwise I wouldn't have been able to edit the form...)

Comment: I've never seen this. Usually, when for some reason an edit in the designer does not sync with the .Designer files (which I assume is what is happening) it never works, no matter how many times you try to compile it, unless you take some other action to manually sync them again.

Comment: It happened to me sometimes with a simple console application as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you checked the "don't compile automatically when build is out of date" checkbox.

Check Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run. My guess is it says "Never build" and "Launch old version".

**EDIT**:

Well, since we can't replicate this issue, it's really hard to help. The last thing that comes to my mind is - export all your VS settings, reset them to C# defaults. If that helps, you can compare the exported settings with the defaults and look for weird stuff.

If it doesn't, try disabling / removing all the plugins you have (or perhaps it would be enough to run VS in safe mode).

If that doesn't help either, try disabling your anti-virus. This is really starting to dig for worms in sand, but it *might* be possible the AV is blocking file operations.

If even that doesn't help, it's time for the reinstall-VS-and-.NET rutine.

Comment: I never knew that existed, I can't imagine why it exists but I'm glad to know where the setting is just in case it gets set. That would drive me nuts!

Comment: Both were "Prompt to build". Thanks anyway.